# Can't access to local server with Android

Tags: android, networking, dns, localhost, mamp

My problem is linked with this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982225/android-local-server-access-over-wifi/

I have a website hosted with MAMP on a Mac mini, connected to a D-Link router. I've got a Wifi-antenna (ubiquiti) which is connected to this router too, it creates a Wifi (**offline**) LAN.
When I try to connect to the Mac mini's IP, it displays the website from other devices (iPhone, Windows PC) but with Android it doesn't work.

I'd like to know how the developper in the link I refered did "***use DNS by redirecting all domains to his custom domain***".
Or if there is another way to work around this... Client devices which connects to the Wifi network shoudn't (I wish) have to configure manually their Android network parameters...

**EDIT:**
ngrok.io is not a solution :

- clients may not have an 3G/LTE connection on their phones
- the adress / IP should be the same every time the Mac reboot

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try this which is a simpler out of the box solution of accessing your local server from anywhere: [Accessing localhost from android over wifi](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20918178/1306419). (I would not recommend this if you are too much concerned about the data that you are testing, going through some other proxy severs.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have 2 problems with this solution : clients may not have an 3G/LTE connection on their phones and every time the Mac reboot we'll have to tell clients (in my case visitors) another xxx.ngrok.io adress...Still sticked, if someone has another work around.

Comment: I don't think 3g is required. WiFi would work. If you want permanent URL,  ngrok provided a paid service for that.

Comment: But my wifi network isn't connected to the Internet, and ngrok delivers an **online** url...