# What is localhost for Android?

Tags: java, android

What is 'localhost' address for Android device?

I'm testing a program using client and server at the same app.

neither `SERVER_IP ="http://localhost"` nor  `"http://127.0.0.1"` works for

```
InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
```

it gives:

> Unable to resolve host `"http://localhost"`: No address associated
>   with hostname android

What is the best way to use localhost?

**UPDATE**
Thanks to all comments: `"http://localhost"` is incorrecct. Right is `"localhost"` or `"127.0.0.1"`  or `"127.0.0.2"`, etc. But I hope the best solution is the marked answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i access my localhost from my android device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device)

Comment: try 127.0.2.2. let me know and are you testing the client on emulator?

Comment: @AllIsWell no. 127.0.0.2 doesn't work on real device.

Comment: @AdamS thanks. I saw this answer. But this is not what I want.

Comment: Ugh, yeah I tried to un-mark that since I realised it was the wrong thing and I couldn't figure out how.

Comment: @trololo 127.0.2.2 is the one you tried or 127.0.0.2?

Comment: For clarification, are you attempting to _run a server on the device_ and _connect to it on the same device_? That's totally different to most localhost questions that pop up on here, I'd recommend updating your question to be a little clearer about that, if that's what you're doing.

Comment: `SERVER_IP ="http://localhost" nor  "http://127.0.0.1"`. Don't specify a protocol and surely not http. Try `SERVER_IP ="localhost" or  "127.0.0.1"`. And indeed, is this in the same app or on the same device?

Comment: @greenapps I found that without http:// all IPs before works: 127.0.0.1, 127.0.2.2, localhost. In all of cases above the s.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString() gives "127.0.0.1"

Comment: @greenapps the same app and the same device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Sockets](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html) communicate over TCP, which is a lower level protocol than HTTP. When you are identifying a [server address](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName(java.lang.String)) for socket communication, use the bare name of the server (for example, "localhost") or a dotted quad (for example "192.168.0.100").

**Don't include http:// or any other scheme**.

If I understand the question correctly and the goal is to open a socket from and to the same machine (the phone), you can just use

```
InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(null);
```

to get the "loopback" interface, which is equivalent to using localhost.

Comment: This is what I want! Thanks a lot. Connection accepted. s.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString() gave me ip_port: /::1:44967

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3380718/1758149) answer, you can simply use your local IP to act as localhost. You can find it by using ipconfig on Windows or ifconfig on linux.

Apparently you can also substitute 10.0.2.2

Comment: @RyPole 10.0.2.2 doesn't work. May be the best idea is to use current IP.

Comment: Yeah, keep in mind it's not your public IP, it's your gateway.

Comment: This IP doesn't work even if I try not "http: //10.0.2.2" but "10.0.2.2"