# JsonObjectRequest - Not working as it not receive any respond

Tags: php, android, json

I want to display the message retrive from http://localhost/test/getcontent1.php in a textview of my splash screen

I have written a php file that will echo jsno data

```
<?php
$strorg = '[{"code":"101","message":"OK"}]';
$str = json_encode($strorg);
echo $str;
?>
```

the output of the link is
  "[{\"code\":\"101\",\"message\":\"OK\"}]"

I have written following code in splashscreen activity

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    final TextView mTxtDisplay;
    mTxtDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDisplay);
    String url = "http://localhost/test/getcontent1.php";
    mTxtDisplay.setText("Begin");
    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
        (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

          @Override

          public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            mTxtDisplay.setText("Response: " + response.toString());
          }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
          @Override
          public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            mTxtDisplay.setText(error.toString());
          }
        });


     Thread timerThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
          try {
            sleep(3000);
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          } finally {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
          }
        }
      };
      timerThread.start(); 
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
  }
}
```

But i didn't get any response. the textview only shows BEGIN
Can sombody have any solution? As i am new to android

Comment: why are you trying to json_encode message which is already encoded ?

Comment: change with `$strorg = array ("code"=>"101","message"=>"OK");`

Comment: @salih still no respond, still getting same only Begin appears

Comment: Also, can you get any output from `"http://localhost/test/getcontent1.php"` in android web browser?

Comment: the output is displaying well as i have paste the output avobe.

Comment: Your java code looks ok. But you should use your computer local ip instead of `localhost`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378501/how-to-browse-localhost-on-android-device

Comment: using local ip not solve my problem, output comes on android browser but my app didn't get any response.

Comment: try to use helper class in http://stackoverflow.com/a/19945676/577159

Comment: if have add      RequestQueue mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    mRequestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
 and now its works